# How can I print the values on textArea JavaFx? Is it possible to change the void to string?

Tags: java, javafx

```
   public void printHashTable()
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\nBucket "+ (i + 1) +" : ");
            LinkedHashEntry entry = table[i];
            while (entry != null)
        {
           
            System.out.print("["+entry.data +" ,"+entry.value+"]>");
            entry = entry.next;
        }            
    }
  }
     // class JavaFx
    // How can I get the value in JAVAFX
       Print_button.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
          textArea.setWrapText(ht.printHashTable());
        
      });
```

> How can I get the value in JAVAFX
> How can I print the values on  textArea JavaFx? Is it possible to change the void to string?
> in this  textArea.setWrapText(ht.printHashTable());

Comment: Why are you calling `setWrapText()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` to build the string, and return it:

```
public String printHashTable() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
        result.append("\nBucket ")
              .append(i + 1)
              .append(" : ");
        LinkedHashEntry entry = table[i];
        while (entry != null) {       
            result.append("[")
                  .append(entry.data)
                  .append(" ,")
                  .append(entry.value)
                  .append("]>");
            entry = entry.next;
        }            
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

And I think you meant

```
printButton.setOnAction(e -> textArea.setText(ht.printHashTable()));
```